# program is not executing from other directories in perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I written some perl code to get some file names and get some values from files. If I execute my perl script from current directory i,e the directory all input files are located, it is executing fine and giving me fine results. If I change the perl script to different directory it saying could not open that file. here is small snippet of code.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
my $opt_filepath;

&GetOptions (
"filepath:s"  => \$opt_filepath,);

my $dir ="/home/priya/scripts/${opt_filepath}/check";  #base directory to look up for the files
    print "$dir \n";
    # Create output csv file
    my $fileName = "Output.csv"; #output redirects to current directory
  # ---- Read and Write as .csv file -------------------------
 open (FILEHANDLER, ">", $fileName) or die("Could not write output File                                                         '$fileName' : $!");
       print FILEHANDLER "Section,";
    print FILEHANDLER "Result";
    print FILEHANDLER "\n";

my @fileName = ();
my @FileContents = ();
my @Result = ();
   opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Unable to read Directory : $!";
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    #Only files not subdirectories
    next unless (-f "$dir/$file");
        next unless ($file =~ m/^EXP_.*/i); #will search for all EXP files
 print "$file \n";
@fileName = split(/_/, $file, 8);
        print FILEHANDLER $fileName[1].",";
open (FH, "<", $file ) or die("Could not open Input File : $!");
        @FileContents = <FH>;
@Result = grep (/^ADDSUB/, @FileContents);
print FILEHANDLER $FileContents[1]."\n";

        close FH;
}
closedir(DIR);
close FILEHANDLER;
exit 0;
```

if execute in the directory which i have all input EXP files, it is executing good and giving me good results. If i copy the code to different directory and execute it is giving me this error

```
>priyascript.pl -filepath test
/home/priya/scripts/test/check
EXPresult_101101_test
Could not open Input File : No such file or directory at priyascript.pl line 31
```

i printed $file to check whether it is passing the file name. It is passing the file name but not opening it. 
I checked with all folder permissions and given 777

Please help me

Comment: this is only small snippet of my code. If there is something missing please ignore

Comment: So where is the line 89 into `idve.pl` ?

Comment: Your code will not execute. There is compilation errors. Declare `@Result` at line 33.

Comment: There are some typo mistakes. Actual code is different. I tried to correct all typo mistakes. Please help me now

Comment: I m using getoptions function to give file directory . I am giving $opt_filepath to give specific directory in that common path. There are so many folders in home/priya/scripts/....../check . While executing script I will give priyascript -filepath test, as a switch . To do processing in that test folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the input file without a path. Instead of

```
open (FH, "<", $file )
```

you should have

```
open (FH, "<", "$dir/$file" )
```

Comment: @Priya: You also don't use `@Result` after you've filled it